# Git permission denied, but can ssh through git shell

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh

I've freshly installed Git, generated SSH pair, added the SSH key to my github account. After all that I've run `ssh -T git@github.com` inside Git Shell and I've got a message about success:

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but Github does not provide shell access.
```

Then I tried to push my commits of my project: created the repository using `git init`, made the commit, added the remote: `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/Project.git`, but after I use `git push origin master` I get the

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

My SSH pair is inside `C://Users/PCUser/.ssh`.

**EDIT:** Also, there is no `config` file inside `C://Users/PCUser/.ssh`, only 2 files: `username` and `username.pub`. Could this be the reason? There is a `config` file inside `MyProject/.git`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:username/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Have you added the key correctly? Check that again. You are supposed to add public key.

Comment: @G_S What do you mean by that? Added to the site. I think I did it correctly. Anyhow, if I didn't wouldn't the `ssh -T git@github.com` give a mistake?

Comment: I don't see any other reason why it shouldn't work. That why I am suggesting to check if you have added correct key.

Comment: @G_S 11 Wouldn't be able to make a mistake even if I tried - github can detect it if I change some numbers/symbols in a key. When I delete the key `ssh -T git@github.com` gives `Permission denied` too, so it does check github.com for a valid key. Github is freaking weird, it's insane. Couldn't they at least make better logs instead of a single `Permission denied` mystery answer?

Comment: This may be a long shot, but is the repo url correct (compared with the SSH-url on Github)? Can you clone the repo somewhere else using the SSH-url? You could try using the HTTPS-url to see if the problem is with the SSH-key.

Comment: If you're running a recent Git, try running `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git push origin master`. That should make the ssh command you're using print verbose output when trying to push.